# Why don't we register broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am confused about the a concept here. I read on many tutorials that in order to get notified when device has booted (say for purpose of re-scheduling an alarm), you need to have a boot_completed broadcast receiver.

However the confusing part is that no where I see a method  like "register(boradcast receiver)". People just have the broadcast receiver class and they have it in manifest. but dont you need some sort of registration process? How will the system know that there is an APP x who has a broadcast receiver y listening for boot events unless explicitly told through registering

Sort of like you create click listener, but you need to register/add it to the button to so it gets called upon clicked.

Can someone clear the confusion for me?

Thank you

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> People just have the broadcast receiver class and they have it in manifest. but dont you need some sort of registration process?

The `<receiver>` element in the manifest has the `<intent-filter>` child element, documenting the `Intent` structure it wishes to receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          package="com.commonsware.android.sysevents.boot"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
            android:targetSdkVersion="6" />
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="false"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/cw"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Here, we are registering a `BroadcastReceiver`, named `OnBootReceiver`, to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts.

> How will the system know that there is an APP x who has a broadcast receiver y listening for boot events unless explicitly told through registering

Android is "explicitly told through registering". It just so happens that the "registering" is done via the manifest, not via Java code in the app.

Comment: So if i do context.registerReceiver() then I dont need to add the broadcast receiver to manifest, right?

Comment: @Snake: Yes, bearing in mind that `registerReceiver()` will not work for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:
You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Except that `registerReceiver()` is ineffective for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, because by the time any code could call `registerReceiver()`, the boot will have already taken place. :-)

Comment: Wow that I never thought of. Great explanation

Comment: @CommonsWare Why doesn't Android send a StickyBroadcast on boot-completion ? In that case, I guess dynamically registering a receiver would work ?

Comment: @AshokBijoyDebnath: There would be no point. By the time you call `registerReceiver()`, **by definition**, the boot will have already occurred. You don't need the broadcast to know that. Besides, sticky broadcasts are deprecated in Android 5.0.