# Unable to reschedule at boot - Android Java

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reset, reboot

I have been unable to schedule my alarm at reboot of phone. I have a `Broadcast Receiver` that I am registering via code. I have the ability to wake the phone when it is asleep and the alarm sets just fine but when trying to schedule the phone at boot using the below broadcast receiver and registering it via code I am having issues. I am NOT able to register it via the `AndroidManifest.xml` so please help me do this using the code below and any modifications it may need. Thank you!

```
  private void SetTheAlarmForNotifications() {

    try {

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

                    //acquire the wakelock and lock the phone from sleeping
                    WakeLocker.acquire(c);

                    //RUN THE NOTIFY EVENT WHEN THE BROADCAST RECEPTION IS RECEIVED
                    NotifyUserOfAddedScheduledItem("", "");
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.kyledenney.staplelist") );

        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.kyledenney.staplelist"),
                0 );
        am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

        //SETUP THE ALARM FOR THE ITEMS IF IT IS NOT SET
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);

        //fake test alarm setting (one time reoccurring alarm
        //that only fires 20 seconds after it is set
        //  am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        //       2000, pi );

        //another fake test that fires the wakeup every minute as a test - but it is a recurring
        //event instead of firing just once - we would probably only want to do this if it was elapsed from
        //a  certain time
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
               1000 * 60 * 1, pi);

        //real alarm setting
       // am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: "I am NOT able to register it via the AndroidManifest.xml" so how do you setting your android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874763/why-dont-we-register-broadcast-receiver-for-boot-completed-events

Comment: That answers the question. How do I do this via XML/Java with putting the BOOT_COMPLETED in the Android Manifest.xml?